# Realm default order of items

Tags: realm

I query data from database. What is default attribute for sorting?
When sort method is not called (used) than is order of items specifified by time of insertion (ASC)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When sort method is not called (used) than is order of items specified by time of insertion (ASC)?

That's a bit of an oversimplification, because the insertion order is retained only until you delete an item, because the last item can be placed in place of the deleted element.

So it's more like, "insertion order until you delete an item, afterwards it's driven by magic"

To ensure a deterministic sort order, store an indexed field and sort by that.